# Ant build fails because of generics - and only on linux

Tags: java, generics, netbeans, ant

I'm trying to build a project of mine on debian (in fact, hudson builds it), and the build fails:

```
[javac] (...)/src/vbp/gui/GUI.java:1569: type javax.swing.DefaultListModel does not take parameters
[javac]     private javax.swing.DefaultListModel<String> listModelInput;
[javac]                                         ^
```

Well, problem is, DefaultListModel should be able to handle generics.

If i'm running the build on my windows-machine with ant, it compiles perfectly fine, only on debian it doesn't work. Ant version is 1.8.0, JDK is OpenJDK 1.6.

My first thought was that Ant somehow used jdk 1.4 or something to compile the code (because the compile error is about generics), and in fact it was written in the build-script generated by netbeans to do so, but when i've changed that to 1.5 or 1.6 nothing changed (and it would be really strange if it would have helped, because the only error i get is with this DefaultListModel class).

I really have no idea what this is about. Maybe I found a bug and the fix just isn't in the debian software repository...

You can check out the project here: 
https://github.com/Klamann/Video-Batch-Processor

Hope you can help :)

---

edit:

OK, this really is a bug in OpenJDK 6. It was solved in OpenJDK 7.

```
public class DefaultListModel extends AbstractListModel  // JDK6 implementation

public class DefaultListModel<E> extends AbstractListModel<E>  // JDK7 implementation
```

They just forgot the <E>...

Well, at least I found my first bug in my favourite programming language :D

Comment: are u sure you managed to change the compiler to 1.5+? How did you confirm that?

Comment: @Saket: The error indicates that the compiler is generics-aware, but it thinks the type doesn't take a parameter.

Comment: wow, this relly seems to be a bug in OpenJDK.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.java
at least it was in 6b14

Comment: Check that on Debian you are also using Open JDK (because it seems to be the only JDK the supports generics in Swing classes). What is your `java -version` on Debian? The same story with NetBeans: you have to use Open JDK for this project (set the project build properties).

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a `-target` level in the build command line?